# Send and receive binary data over web sockets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation, websocket

It is possible to send and receive binary data over web sockets in Javascript? Could I, for example, implement an SSH client using web sockets?

Comment: Chad, was your question answered? If so can you select the answer you think was best, or if not, can you give feedback on what you are still looking for?

Comment: note that in backend you must only send the binary data, if also pass in text data, binary may be overwritten, the data received is always `e.data`

Answer (score 51):

The next draft ([hybi-07](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-07)) of the WebSockets specification is being implemented in most browsers and it will add built-in binary support to the protocol and API.

However, until then, WebSockets payload is encoded as UTF-8. In order to send binary data you must use some way of encoding the binary data as UTF-8.

There are many options but here are two that I have used:

**UTF-8**:

You can actually encode a byte stream directly to UTF-8.

The python to encode and decode would look something like this:

```
from codecs import (utf_8_encode, utf_8_decode,
                    latin_1_encode, latin_1_decode)

utf_8_encode(unicode(buf, 'latin-1'))[0]      # encode

latin_1_encode(utf_8_decode(utf8_buf)[0])[0]  # decode
```

In Javascript:

```
chr = data.charCodeAt(N)  // to 'decode' at position N of the message

// Enocde array of bytes (0-255) to UTF-8
data = array.map(function (num) {
    return String.fromCharCode(num); }).join('');
```

UTF-8 encode notes:

- For binary data that is evenly distributed across value 0-255, then size of the payload is 50% larger than the raw binary data.
- The Flash WebSockets emulator [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) may have trouble with the encoding of 0 (zero).

**Base 64**:

In python:

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

data = b64encode(buf)    # encode binary buffer to b64

buf = b64decode(data)    # decode b64 to binary buffer
```

To encode and decode the messages on the Javascript side:

```
data = window.btoa(msg)  // Encode to base64

msg = window.atob(data)  // Decode base64
msg.charCodeAt(N)        // Read decode byte at N
```

Base 64 notes:

- Evenly distributed binary data (0-255) will be 33% larger than the raw data.
- There is less python side overhead to base64 encoding than there is to UTF-8 encoding. However, there is a bit more Javascript side overhead to decoding base64 (UTF-8 doesn't need decoding in Javascript since the browser has already converted the UTF-8 to the Javascript native UTF-16).
- **Update**: This assumes the binary data is encoded to a UTF-8 string as shown above with character values that range from 0-255. Specifically, window.atob does not support character values above 255. See this [mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213047). The same limitation applies to Chrome.

**websockify**:

[WebSockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) is a proxy/bridge that allows a WebSockets capable browser to communicate with any arbitrary binary service. It was created to allow [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) to communicate with existing VNC servers. websockify uses base64 encode/decode of the binary data and also provides a `websock.js` library for use in Javascript. The `websock.js` has an API similar to regular WebSocket but it is handles binary data transparently and is designed to communicate with websockify. **Disclaimer**: I created websockify and noVNC.

**ssh client**:

Technically you could implement a browser ssh client over WebSockets (and I've considered it), however, this will require doing SSH encryption and decryption in the browser which will be slow. Given that WebSockets has an encrypted WSS (TLS) mode, it probably makes more sense to do plain telnet over WebSocket WSS.

In fact, websockify includes an example telnet client.

You would launch websockify on HOSTNAME like this (telnetd is from krb5-telnetd):

```
sudo ./websockify 2023 --web . --wrap-mode=respawn -- telnetd -debug 2023
```

Then navigate to `http://HOSTNAME:2023/wstelnet.html?hostname=HOSTNAME&port=2023`

See the [websockify README](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/README.md) for more information. To use WSS encryption you will need to create an SSL key as described on the [noVNC advanced usage wiki page](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/wiki/Advanced-usage)

Comment: Would the down-voter care to clarify why the downvote so that I can fix the answer (if possible)? Thanks.

Comment: I have trouble with the base64 solution. For me, it seems, that if the data that has to be encoded has invalid UTF-8 characters in it, calling atob on it results in "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5" on chrome or "String contains an invalid character" on firefox. For example, atob("aGVsbG8=") gives "hello", but atob("AQAAA") results in that error.

Comment: @marc40000, you can encode (window.btoa) any string (no matter what sort of weird binary/unicode values it has in it). To decode a string (window.atob), it must be valid standard base64 encoded. Which means it can only use the standard 64 base64 characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /), and it must be padded to a four byte boundary with "=". In your case, your error is because "AQAAA" is not base64 encoded. It is too short and not padded. This works: atob("AQAAAA==")

Comment: About binary support status of browsers:
http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/reports/clients/index.html

Comment: @kanaka Even when the next draft of websocket is rolled out, we still can't send binary data directly since JavaScript is text-based and ultimately some conversion (performance overhead) would be needed right?

Comment: @Pacerier, Javascript now supports typed arrays (arraybuffers) and Blobs which are native binary types. These can be sent and received over WebSocket directly with no conversion necessary. These types (and the Websocket support) are supported in current releases of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and will be supported in IE10.

Comment: @kanaka (Mar 10): Seems like you can't encode *any* string: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213047 This contradicts your statement.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen, good call. The window.btoa function is limited to strings with character values in the 0-255 range. It doesn't affect the answer which first encodes bytes (0-255) to a string and then runs btoa against it. Base64 encoding is generally defined in terms of 8 bit ASCII so it's not exactly clear what it means to base64 encode an arbitrary unicode string. However, I did imply that you could do so in my comment, so thanks for the catch. Mea culpa. The rest of the comment still applies since marc40000's issue was with atob, not btoa (even though it does give a similar DOM error).

Comment: you have the `atob` and `btoa` functions the wrong way round in code comments... `atob` _decodes from b64_ and `btoa` _encodes to b64_ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp

Comment: @Anentropic sure enough. Fixed. That always trips me up. As best I can tell the a is 'ascii' and the b is 'binary'. But given these functions existed prior to binary support in the browser, and given that the decoded data isn't _really_ binary (but another string), it was an odd acronym choice.

Comment: yes I'm also guessing they mean 'ascii' and 'binary' ... I think it's much better on the python side where things are explicitly `b64encode`  and `b64decode` ...you know what you're getting there!

Answer (score 9):

One good and safe way to send and receive binary data is with base64 or base128 (where 128 has just 1/7 overhead instead of 1/3).

Yes an SSH Client is possible.

A proof for this is that there are already a lot of solutions out there that run in common browsers, but most of them still needs a custom server side implementation.
You can look here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH

Comment: -1, any UTF-8 compatible encoding will work. Also, describing plugins as 100% Javascript is a bit misleading since plugins require download and installation and are generally not cross-browser compatible. I.e plugins are using browser facilities not available in the normal Javascript context.

Answer (score 8):

Now you can send and receive binary data easily, this article explain lot of thinks : http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/02/06/parsing-binary-protocol-data-javascript-typedarrays-blobs/

Here is how I receive binary numpy array sent with python (my_nparray.tobytes()) in my browser:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:51234");
ws.binaryType = 'blob';
var buffer;

ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(evt.data);
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(e)
    {
        buffer = new Uint16Array(e.target.result);  // arraybuffer object
    });
};
```

You can convert typed array to javascript array with this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer.slice());
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe WebSockets could somehow be combined with this: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/TypedArrays/

Comment: that is already possible. see [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#websocket)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement a SSH client in a browser using WebSockets without the help of a web server that will act as the SSH client or as sort of WebSocket-to-SSH proxy.

The WebSocket protocol allows to send arbitrary binary data (not even UTF-8 or Base-64 encoded) BUT that data are encapsulated in frames whose format is defined by WebSocket protocol (see [RFC6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455)) and has nothing to do with SSH protocol. This encapsulation is hidden by the Javascript at web browser side but the server that receives the WebSocket connection receives it and must also implement it so that connection can be established.

So it could be possible to exchange the SSH protocol as payload of the WebSocket protocol but not to implement a standard SSH client.