# Sending hex char F6 to a websocket in C#

Tags: c#, websocket4net

I'm trying to send a hex character to a WebSocket4net socket with a C# client. If I send either of the following syntaxes, it works and sends '12'.

```
_webSocketClient.Send("\x12");
_webSocketClient.Send("\u0012");
```

When I try to send this, it sends 'C3 B6'.

```
_webSocketClient.Send("\xF6");
```

I don't want to use the overloaded method for sending binary data. I'd like to send this as a hex string. How can I send this character?

I'm setting up the Websocket like this:

```
 _webSocketClient = new WebSocket4Net.WebSocket("wss://www.example.com", "", null, null, "Mozilla","http://www.example.com", WebSocketVersion.None);
```

Comment: May be look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794334/how-would-i-send-and-receive-packets-over-a-websocket-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but I don't find the linked question a great help.

Comment: Looks like it's sending the string using UTF-8 encoding and you want ASCII encoding.  I'm not familiar with that library so I don't know if there's a simple way to change the encoding that it uses (aside from doing `Encoding.GetBytes` yourself and using the byte array overload, which you said you don't want to do).

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work either:_webSocketClient.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0xF6}));

Comment: No, I meant `byte[] buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\xF6");` then `_webSocketClient.Send(buf, 0, buf.Length);`.  If you call the overload that takes a string it's going to convert it to UTF-8 no matter how you created the string.

Comment: That sends the byte 3F, not F6.If I change it to byte[] buf = { 0xF6 };, it sends the correct byte. You're right about using Default encoding: your suggestions works if I change it to that.

Comment: Oh, right, because ASCII is 7-bit.  That should be `Encoding.Default` for ANSI which I believe is 8-bit.  Oops.  (Shows how much I work with non-Unicode encodings, I guess.)

Comment: Is there any way to send that byte in any way using a string? I don't want to use the overload that takes a byte array if at all possible.